# why sometimes this error occurs " the remote name could not be resolved:'api.opentok.com'

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I am using the dot net sdk of opentok and it runs well, but sometimes this error occurs , which is explained in image[image]

[image]

What might I be doing wrong?? Some more error occurs sometime like

```
  `Session was abruptly closed`
```

Comment: can you give me a sessionId that causes this problem? I have not seen this before. Does this happen consistently, or is there a pattern (bad wifi? Browser? )

Comment: I generate new session every time 2 users chat......and these errors occur 60% to 70% time and rest of time these errors don't occur.

Comment: 2_MX40NDY4NjEzMn4xMjIuMTc3LjUwLjEyM35XZWQgTWFyIDI2IDIzOjQ3OjI1IFBEVCAyMDE0fjAuMjM3NzIyODF-
   This is a sessionId which worked well for 10-15 minutes and then    suddenly video chatting was gone, Session was disconnected perhaps

Comment: This issue might be too involved for StackOverflow. I don't know why this would happen, you should email support@tokbox.com

Comment: Did you fix this issue? If you did, it would be great if you could share what happened.